# How to pass NSIndexPath object with addTarget method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to pass NSIndexPath to @selector.
So I used following code, but there is no argument like withObject.
How can I do it?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

// User taps expanded row
if (selectedIndex == indexPath.row){
    selectedIndex = -1;
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

// User taps different row
if (selectedIndex != -1){
    NSIndexPath *prevPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:selectedIndex inSection:1];
    selectedIndex = (int)indexPath.row;
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:prevPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}

// User taps new row with unexpanded
selectedIndex = (int)indexPath.row;
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

[favoriteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(favoritePressed:) withObject:indexPath forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[normalButton addTarget:self action:@selector(normalPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[halfButton addTarget:self action:@selector(halfPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

}

-(void)favoritePressed:(NSIndexPath *)path{
}
```

Comment: Add tag, favoriteButton.tag = selectedIndex
and get tag like this favoriteButton.tag

Comment: @aBilal17 But you know, IndexPath has two argument row and section. I have had used already tags. But the section is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
-(void)favoritePressed:(UIButton *)sender{
    //CustomCell : your custom UITableViewCell class name
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell) [[sender superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
}
```

**NOTE:**

If you set button in content view of CustomCell this will work for you otherwise you need to add other superview for getting the cell.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to do this. You can find the touch point on button click and convert that touch point in to your table frame, and through that point you can get indexpath.

```
-(void)favoritePressed:(UIButton *)sender{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below may work for certain condition but your button may be a inside other view inside a cell. In that case you may not find the cell.

```
CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell) [[sender superview] superview];
```

It is better to use it like this.

```
- (void)btnFavoriteTapped:(UIButton *)sender {

    id view = [sender superview];

    while ([view isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]] == NO) {
    view = [view superview];
    }

    CustomCell *selectedCell = (CustomCell *)view;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:selectedCell];
}
```